# How to run google colab from terminal?

Tags: terminal, google-colaboratory

I am running a deep learning model in google colab and it works fine with colab notebook. The problem is as the training of deep learning model progresses in the cloud colab notebook, my own computers cpu and memory usage also starts to go up. The RAM usage for the colab notebook browser window alone is more than 500 MB and it keeps climbing as the training progresses.

In google colab we have to keep open our running notebooks to train the model else we will lose all our previous work and it stops training. Can I run google colab from my terminal window instead of browser? Is there any way to force google colab to run in the cloud alone, that is, to run the notebook without opening the computer?

Answer (score 7):

Instructions for local execution are available here:

http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

If you combine these with an SSH tunnel, you can run the backend on your own GCE VMs, AWS, or anywhere else you like.