# How to open an interactive Python prompt in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How does one open an interactive Python console/shell/prompt within Google Colab? Is it possible? An iPython prompt would be ideal but a regular prompt would suffice.

Also, it would be significantly more useful if the console's interpreter shared access to the variables/state with the Colab notebook's kernel.

Comment: Nevermind, mistunderstood the question -- the closest method I know of is `!jupyter console`, but variables aren't shared. For some reason, `!jupyter console --existing` is broken. If you're fine with running Colab locally, it probably [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075748/how-to-run-google-colab-from-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

`!jupyter console --existing` appears to hang with no output because it is waiting to acquire the GIL in the same process as the notebook's runtime that is executing the ! magic, which isn't going to give it up until the ! is done. For the same reason I don't think it's going to be easy to get a subprocess invocation to share state with the notebook's runtime. 
Obvs. you could program your own input() + eval() in a loop to simulate a py prompt that shared the env with your notebook.